# Why doesn't the C# ternary operator work with delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, ternary-operator

When branching to select a function, it might make sense to use the ternary operator to select a function, but this is impossible.  Why?

```
public class Demo {
    protected bool branch;
    protected void demo1 () {}
    protected void demo2 () {}
    public Action DoesntWork() {
        return branch ? demo1 : demo2;
    }
}
```

The compiler produces the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `method group' to `System.Action'
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that `demo1` is not a simple expression, it is a *method*. And methods can be overriden, so it is not actually *one* method, it is a *method group*. Consider the following example:

```
public class Demo {
    protected bool branch;
    protected void demo1 (int) {}
    protected void demo1 () {}
    protected void demo2 () {}
    public Action DoesntWork() {
        return branch ? demo1 : demo2; //Error
        return demo1; //ok
    }
}
```

Now, `demo1` is overloaded, so which one of the two versions should be used? The answer is that the overloaded function is selected by using the context in which the function is used.

In the `return demo1` it is obvious, it expects an `Action`.

But in the `return branch? demo1 : demo2;` the context is not so easy. The ternary operator first tries to match the type of `demo1` with that of `demo2`, but that is another *method group* so there is no help there. The compiler does not look beyond and fails.

The solution is to make clear the type expected from the method group:

```
return branch? new Action(demo1) : demo2;

return branch? (Action)demo1 : demo2;

Action d1 = demo1;
return branch? d1 : demo2;
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the type inference fails, and that you can use a cast instead of `new`.

Answer (score 9):

You have to explicitly create the delegate of the appropriate type.  Normally, you can just use `demo1` to refer to a `System.Action`, but that is only because the compiler can infer the type based on the usage and creates the delegate for you.  In this case, the compiler doesn't know that your method should be converted to `System.Action` when used within the ternary operator.

If you supply this yourself for even one of the arguments, it will work:

```
public Action DoesWork() 
{
    return branch ? demo1 : new Action(demo2);
}
```

Since this returns `new Action` explicitly for one argument, the compiler can infer that the other should be converted appropriate to a `System.Action`, and it will compile successfully.