# C# functional programming: cannot reference method, need new Action()

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, action

I was writing some logging code, and I had to invoke either of two methods with the same signature:

```
void Error(string, Exception)
void Warn(string, Exception)
```

I decided to approach this with functional programming instead of an if/else. I have a `bool wasHandled` to determine which method to invoke. I tried:

```
Action<string, Exception> logAction = wasHandled ? _logger.Warn : _logger.Error;
```

But the compiler / intellisense complained with:

> Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Instead, I had to write it like this:

```
var logAction = wasHandled ? new Action<string, Exception>(_logger.Warn) : _logger.Error;
```

I get the bonus of `var` but I really hate that I have to explicitly invoke `new Action....`.

Why does the former not work?

Comment: [The answer to this question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015747/why-does-funcbool-test-value-f-f-not-compile) It's not identical, but it's a similar issue.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Sadly the question was changed midway (from `var` to `Func<>`) so the responses are mixed.

Comment: Note that you can even write `var logAction = wasHandled ? (Action<string, Exception>)_logger.Warn : _logger.Error;`, so using the cast instead of the constructor (no real difference in generated code)

Comment: @xanatos The response marked as the answer is correct (and answers both cases)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes... But the response is split in two... and in truth it doesn't explain why `Func<bool> value = F` works while `Func<bool> value = true ? F : F` doesn't. The answer seems to handwave it a little

Comment: This seems to be better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26369348/613130 Both answer in this one go in the same direction, and they are quite easy to comprehend.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5186394/613130 (but the question was more complex... Robinson's answer nails it well.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't characterise this as "functional programming", especially seeing as `Warn()` and `Error()` are likely to have side-effects (outputting a message)

Comment: I would concur with @MatthewWatson: what you are doing here is not functional programming. You are using the service locator pattern to ask for a function, thus the function that contains this line of code is no longer a pure function.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work cause the type of `_logger.Warn` is the *method group*.

Unlike many functional languages, C# has method (function) overloading, so `MethodName` can mean any of methods with different signatures but with the same name.

Perhaps the C# compiler could handle this situation by the special way, but it doesn't.